# Rewrite the query to get output for cross years?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
         sum(case
                 when "year"  = '2016' then "svalue"
                 ELSE 0
             END) as 'sva_2016',
         sum(case
                 when "year"  = '2017' then "svalue"
                 ELSE 0
             END) as 'sva_2017',
         sum(case
                 when "year"  = '2018' then "svalue"
                 ELSE 0
             END) as 'sva_2018',
         sum(case
                 when "year"  = '2019' then "svalue"
                 ELSE 0
             END) as 'sva_2019',
         sum(case
                 when "year"  = '2016' then "ltr"
                 ELSE 0
             END) as 'lva_2016',
         sum(case
                 when "year"  = '2017' then "ltr"
                 ELSE 0
             END) as 'lva_2017',
         sum(case
                 when "year"  = '2018' then "ltr"
                 ELSE 0
             END) as 'lva_2018',
         sum(case
                 when "year"  = '2019' then "ltr"
                 ELSE 0
             END) as 'lva_2019',
         'Apr 1 - Jan 31' as 'Period',
         "code" as 'FACode'
FROM  "FCJOIN" 
WHERE    "code"  IN
    (
    SELECT "fccode"
    FROM  "fcdetails" 
    )
 AND    "month"  between '04'  and  '12'
 AND    "year"  IN ( '2016'  , '2017'  , '2018'  , '2019'  )
GROUP BY  "code"
```

The above query gives me the correct out put for svalues and ltr for

- April 2016- December 2016
- April 2017- December 2017
- April 2018- December 2018
- April 2019- December 2019

Now I want to get the values of svalues and ltrs for the period of

- April 2016- January 2017
- April 2017- January 2018
- April 2018- January 2019
- April 2019- January 2020

Comment: I _strongly_ recommend not storing your date information in separate year and month columns.  This will only make your life very hard.

Comment: Can you please add sample data and expected output to get better answer

Comment: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

You may use CAST("year" + '-' + "month" + '-01' AS DATETIME) to compare operations.

Btw. it is good example to use [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) operator.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the year/month to a date and use date comparisons:

```
select f.code,
       sum(case when v.dte >= '2016-04-01' and v.dte < '2017-04-01'
                then f.svalue else 0
           end) as svalue_2016,
       . . . 
       sum(case when v.dte >= '2016-04-01' and v.dte < '2017-04-01'
                then f.ltr else 0
           end) as ltr_2016,
       . . . 
from fcjoin f cross apply
     (values (datefromparts(f.year, f.month, 1)) 
     ) v(dte)
where f.code in (select fd.fccode from fcdetails fd)
group by code;
```

I removed all the double quotes, because they just complicate the query.